# Why does MPMediaEntity / MPMediaItem use valueForProperty?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmediaitem

The [docs for MPMediaEntity](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaEntity_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MPMediaEntity) (and therefor MPMediaItem) explain that to access properties, you must use `valueForProperty:` and then it defines a [list of keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/General_Media_Item_Property_Keys) that will return properties. I'm curious as to why this metadata has to be queried in this way. Why doesn't MPMediaEntity simply expose object properties or getters?

Example:

```
NSString* title = (NSString*)[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
```

Why not something like:

```
NSString* title = item.title
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This pattern is used in a few cases in addition to `MPMediaEntity`. An example includes `NSURL` (using `getResourceValue:forKey:error:`.

The most likely reason for this pattern is because there are so many possible values and new values can appear over time. The interface is cleaner by having one method (and a growing list of keys). Otherwise the class would have dozens of properties and the class interface would change every time a new value is added.

It also makes it easier to implement some of the other methods like `enumerateValuesForProperties:usingBlock:` and `canFilterByProperty:` because you simply provide keys representing the values. If the class had plain old properties for each value, implementing such methods would be much more difficult.

Comment: Great. I figured there would be no harm in creating a category for convenience access: https://github.com/hodgesmr/MPMediaItem-Accessors

Answer (score 1):

In the current SDK, Apple has defined type-safe getters for you.